# Why do some container-elements have a height of 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The parent element of `#question-header` on this exact page has a height of around `54px`, but actually contains most of the page's visible content:

[image: picture of element with unexpectedly low height]

There are also cases of such elements with a height of `0px` (see the `#page` element on [rockpapershotgun](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/)).

Neither properties `element.clientHeight`, `element.offsetHeight`, `element.scrollHeight`, nor `element.getBoundingClientRect()` return the real values.

Why is that and is there a fast and reliable way to get the actual dimensions of the element? I'm using it as a loop-break-criterion in a top-down traversal of the DOM-tree in an effort to safe computation time, hence why it would be too computationally expensive to also consider each element's children. And I cannot use libraries.

Comment: Container elements may have 0 height/width because the children are either floated (without clearing), absolutely positioned or it (the parent) has set dimensions.